# The instruction is so hard for me to understand

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

A doctor gave me a bottle of medicine (100 tablets).
On the bottle's side, I saw the intruction for adult dosage:

> One tablet to be taken three times daily

I was so confused how to swallow **the same one tablet three times daily**, so
I called the doctor and she told me this:

> Take one tablet each time at 8-hour intervals.

Because there are 24 hours in a day, this means I have to take three tablets daily.
Now I am trying to digest this sentence

> One tablet to be taken three times daily

Why is its meaning equivalent to this:

> Take one tablet each time at 8-hour intervals.

Comment: I didn't get your question. Could you possibly rephrase it, please? 
Let me answer what I could understand... Since daily means every day. And a single day consists of 24 hours.. You are supposed to take medicine three times a day. So, in other words, you are supposed to take medicine three times in 24 hours... Divide 24 by 3, you will get 8... And so, you can also say that you are supposed to take medicine at 8-hour intervals..

Comment: I had to upvote this just for the usages of "swallow" and "digest". Those are great puns!

Comment: "one tablet" is the *number* of tablets to be taken. If the instructions had said "Take *the one* tablet three times daily"  you would have had to tie a string around the tablet so you could fish it out of your gullet after taking it, so that you could retake it :)

Comment: On separate occasions I found my brother and father trying to cut a tablet into thirds thanks to these instructions (we’re English and neither my father nor brother are stupid men). I wonder if this is grammatically correct in all honesty. Would it make more sense to “take one tablet thrice daily”?

Comment: @HellbabyG - It would clearly not make more sense to simply change "three times" to "thrice".  That is a simply synonym substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One tablet** refers to the dosage. That's how much you are supposed to take each time you take the medicine.

**Three times daily** is the frequency. That's how often you are supposed to administer a dose.

Had the instructions read like this instead:

> *Three tablets to be taken one time daily*

that would mean you would ingest three tablets all at once (or one right after the other), and do that once a day.

However, your instructions say:

> *One tablet to be taken three times daily*

so you take one tablet at a time, and you do that three times a day (with roughly eight hours between each dose). For most people, that means one tablet in the morning, one at bedtime, and one in-between during the middle of the day.

Comment: Thank you for the help, J.R. Your answers are always helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The adverbial ("three times daily") modifies the instruction ("one tablet to be taken"), not its subject ("one tablet").

You can determine this because the adverb 'daily' can only refer to the action ('taken'), not the object ('tablet').